# Native RNDIS USB tethering support for OSX

Tags: usb, tethering, android

Android phones can be USB tethered via RNDIS protocol on Windows and Linux. As far as I understood Apple does not provide RNDIS driver for OSX.

Are there RNDIS drivers for OSX by third party (Android vendor) or community?

I don't want to use any any app for tethering, I want the real thing, as other operating systems can do it, so please no suggestions for alternative methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since then, this driver has come out. It's FOSS too.

http://www.joshuawise.com/horndis

Comment: Tested it on Kindle 5th Generation and works like treat :)

Comment: Just tested with Nexus 5 an Maverick. Works!

Comment: That's great to hear. I haven't had a chance to test with Yosemite but I can see on GitHub that the project is still active.

Comment: Works with Yosemite and BeagleBones, but does not yet support El Capitan.

Comment: currently working with mac os catalina 10.15. check this if any installation issue : https://github.com/jwise/HoRNDIS/issues/102

Answer (score 2):

RNDIS is a Microsoft-proprietary protocol and it's highly unlikely that Apple is going to support it just for the sake of Android tethering.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNDIS

Your best chance is for a 3rd party to write a Mac OS X driver for RNDIS. Don't expect this to be free (as in beer) though.

However you should be able to use the Android phone as a USB dial-up modem, which was the standard way for tethering before the iPhone came about and still a supported method in OS X and others.

Comment: Thanks! That what I was slowly realized. Nowadays using wifi tethering.

Answer (score 1):

horndis is a brilliant solution - just started using it yesterday and it's completely stable

I couldn't get my Andriod phone to work as a USB modem.

I compiled it from source for 10.6.8 then used `packagemaker` and the included `packagemaker` project file to create a package to install.

Only gotcha was using `sudo su` to change the ownership and permissions on the installed kext manually

```
sudo su
chown -R root:wheel /System/Library/Extensions/HoRNDIS.kext

chmod -R 755 /System/Library/Extensions/HoRNDIS.kext
```

Comment: They have binary distributions nowadays and almost works like a charm.